# Spring GET Rest - Reason: Expected to find an object with property ['id'] in path $ but found 'net.minidev.json.JSONArray'

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/rest")
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Validated
public class WarehouseController {
....


@GetMapping(path = "v2/warehouses/limited")
 public List<WarehouseSimpleListDto> getRestrictedWarehouses(
            @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "{}") WarehouseSearchFilterSimpleDto filter
    ) {
```

My cucumber test:

```
 Given I request GET at endpoint:
    """
    /api/rest/v2/warehouses/limited?filter={"shipper_ids":[333444]}
    """
    Then the response status code should be 200
```

where:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.Set;

@Data
public class WarehouseSearchFilterSimpleDto {
    @JsonProperty("shipper_ids")
    private Set<Long> shipperIds;
    @JsonProperty("carrier_ids")
    private Set<Long> carrierIds;
}
```

What is going on? I have very similar endpoint that works! When I change filter dto to the working on (identical!) then its OK. Magic for me

Error:

```
. Reason: Expected to find an object with property ['id'] in path $ but found 'net.minidev.json.JSONArray'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.
2023-04-08 22:17:50.908  INFO 13016 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] e.t.c.l.CustomRequestLoggingFilter       : F1BE16AC5518488DA1B0FBF90CE1C38B RQ BEGIN [GET /api/rest/v2/warehouses/limited?filter=%7B%22shipper_ids%22:%5B1057128%5D%7D];headers=[user-agent:"cucumber/tests", host:"localhost:8080", connection:"Keep-Alive", accept-encoding:"gzip"]
2023-04-08 22:17:50.941  INFO 13016 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] e.t.c.l.CustomRequestLoggingFilter       : F1BE16AC5518488DA1B0FBF90CE1C38B RQ END [GET /api/rest/v2/warehouses/limited?filter=%7B%22shipper_ids%22:%5B1057128%5D%7D]
2023-04-08 22:17:50.958  INFO 13016 --- [           main] p.a.common.integration.ApiStepdefs       :  Cannot extract ID from body <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</title><style type="text/css">body {
font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;}
 h1, h2, h3, b {
color:white;background-color:#525D76;}
 h1 {
font-size:22px;}
 h2 {
font-size:16px;}
 h3 {
font-size:14px;}
 p {
font-size:12px;}
 a {
color:black;}
 .line {
height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}
</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1></body></html>. Reason: Expected to find an object with property ['id'] in path $ but found 'java.lang.String'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.
```

**UPDATE**  mapping in object works ONLY for String fields!

Answer (score 0):

I had to add some mapper in my project:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StringToWarehouseSearchSimpleDto implements Converter<String, WarehouseSearchFilterSimpleDto> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows({IOException.class})
    public WarehouseSearchFilterSimpleDto convert(String source) {
        return objectMapper.readValue(source, WarehouseSearchFilterSimpleDto.class);
    }
}
```